# Filtering columns presented as comboboxes in a split form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a split form based on a table (tblMain). The form shows many columns some of which are textboxes and others are comboboxes. I can easily sort and filter every column in a datasheet part of the form except of two columns.

These two columns are comboboxes which have the same control source and same row source table however with the following difference:

```
cboPUNUM: 
control source tblMain.[PU_ID]; 
row source SELECT tblPU.[PU_ID], tblPU.PUNUM FROM tblPU;

cboPUTYPE: 
control source tblMain.[PU_ID]; 
row source SELECT tblPU.[PU_ID], tblPU.PUTYPE FROM tblPU;
```

Table tblPU has the following structure:

```
PU_ID  PUNUM  PUTYPE
1      11234  SMC
2      21234  DPL
3      11234  NEC
4      21123  SMC
and so on...
```

The idea is to have two separate columns for PUNUM and PUTYPE in the split form and be able to filter them.

Both columns in the split form show all available values in checkboxes for filtering in the drop-down list on top of columns until the filter is applied:

[image]

The problem is that I can filter only one of these columns (see the picture below). For example if I select 84174 in the PUNUM field then I lose an ability to filter PUTYPE field. Ideally PUTYPE should give me an option to check FHP or ADH but checkboxes don't appear in a drop-down list.

[image]

And vise versa, if I start from filtering the PUTYPE, i.e. I select FHP and expect the PUNUM to have many options but it doesn't show checkboxes for filtering (see below).

[image]

Please advise what I can do with this as I have no ideas...?

P.S. DLookup function instead of comboboxes doesn't allow to filter columns at all.

I know that I can base the form on a query and save DLookup expressions in that query, but it significantly slows down the performance.

Comment: First, you bound two form controls to the same table field which forces the two controls to always carry the same value. Consider redesigning. Second, please illustrate your scenario better or provide a screenshot or something as it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do: "show all available values in checkboxes for filtering in drop-down list"???

Comment: Thanks, Parfait, I added some pictures to illustrate my question. Yes, I realize that both controls are bound to the same source and primary key for both will always be the same for a particular record. But I apply filter to the entire database with many records. For example, PUNUM 84174 is written in the source table under two PK (PU_ID):  32 and 63. One of them has PUTYPE FHP and another has AHD. Maybe the structure is not ideal but it is what it is. So when I select 84174 in the filter drop-down list, it shows records with PU_ID 32 and 63. So shouldn't PUTYPE show the same?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Looks like I was over thinking the issue...

I just changed the query for the split form and included tblPU with those two fields. And then converted form controls to text boxes and sourced them to that fields directly. Works as I wanted.